# Array Size affects code results.

Tags: c++, arrays

In the following code, in the Fluid class I have defined a 3D matrix of size [M][N][4]. (Where, for test reasons, M=N)
When I run the code with values of M and N under 105, it works perfectly, but if I increase the value of them, the compiler (Xcode) points to

```
Fluid U_func;
```

and writes

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Am I forgetting to declare something??
Thanks!

Here is my code,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
const int M = 100;
const int N = 100;
const double gama = 1.4;
const double alpha = 3;

const double Time = 0.3;
const double Cf = 0.75; //  The desired CFL number

const double x_1 = 0;
const double x_2 = 1;
const double y_1 = 0;
const double y_2 = 1;

const double rho1 = 1.5;
const double v1 = 0.0;
const double u1 = 0.0;
const double p1 = 1.5;

const double rho2 = 0.5323;
const double v2 = 1.206;
const double u2 = 0.0;
const double p2 = 0.3;

const double rho3 = 0.5323;
const double v3 = 0.0;
const double u3 = 1.206;
const double p3 = 0.3;

const double rho4 = 0.138;
const double v4 = 1.206;
const double u4 = 1.206;
const double p4 = 0.029;


class Fluid
{
public:
    double Array_U[M+1][N+1][4], Array_Prime[M+1][N+1][4],Array_F[M+1][N+1][4],Array_G[M+1][N+1][4], dU_dY[M+1][N+1][4], dU_dX[M+1][N+1][4], dU_dT[M+1][N+1][4], dF_dT[M+1][N+1][4], dG_dT[M+1][N+1][4], dF_dY[M+1][N+1][4], dG_dX[M+1][N+1][4];
    double dx=(double(x_2-x_1))/double(M);
    double dy=(double(y_2-y_1))/double(N);

    void SetInitialConditions(int initialX, int finalX, int initialY, int finalY, double rho, double u, double v, double p)  // initial conditions
    {
        for (int i = initialX; i<=finalX; i++)
            for (int j = initialY ; j<=finalY; j++) {
                Array_U[i][j][0]=rho;
                Array_U[i][j][1]=rho*u;;
                Array_U[i][j][2]=rho*v;
                Array_U[i][j][3]= (p/(gama-1)) + 0.5*rho*(u*u+v*v);

            }

        // get initial Uprime
        for (int i = 0; i <= M ; i++) {
            for (int j = 0 ; j <= N ; j++) {
                for (int k = 0 ; k < 4 ; k++) {
                    Array_Prime[i][j][k]=Array_U[i][j][k];
                }
            }
        }
        // get intial dU_dX and dU_dY
        for (int i=0 ; i<M; i++) {
            for (int j=0 ; j<N ; j++) {
                for (int k=0; k<4; k++) {
                    dU_dY[i][j][k]=dU_dX[i][j][k]=0;
                }
            }
        }
        for(int k=0 ; k<4 ; k++)
        {
            dU_dX[M][N][k]=0;
            dU_dY[M][N][k]=0;
        }

    }
    void get_F(double Array_U[M+1][N+1][4], double Array_F[M+1][N+1][4])
    {
        for (int i=0; i<=M; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<=N; j++)
            {
                double u=Array_U[i][j][1]/Array_U[i][j][0];
                double v=Array_U[i][j][2]/Array_U[i][j][0];
                double rho=Array_U[i][j][0];
                double P=(gama-1)*(Array_U[i][j][3]-0.5*(Array_U[i][j][1]*Array_U[i][j][1]+Array_U[i][j][2]*Array_U[i][j][2])/
                            Array_U[i][j][0]);
                Array_F[i][j][0]=Array_U[i][j][1];
                Array_F[i][j][1]=rho*u*u+P;
                Array_F[i][j][2]=rho*u*v;
                Array_F[i][j][3]=(Array_U[i][j][3]+P)*u;
            }
        }

    }
    void get_G(double Array_U[M+1][N+1][4], double Array_G[M+1][N+1][4])
    {
        for (int i=0; i<=M; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<=N; j++)
            {
                double u=Array_U[i][j][1]/Array_U[i][j][0];
                double v=Array_U[i][j][2]/Array_U[i][j][0];
                double rho=Array_U[i][j][0];
                double P=(gama-1)*(Array_U[i][j][3]-0.5*(Array_U[i][j][1]*Array_U[i][j][1]+Array_U[i][j][2]*Array_U[i][j][2])/
                                   Array_U[i][j][0]);
                Array_G[i][j][0]=Array_U[i][j][2];
                Array_G[i][j][1]=rho*u*v;
                Array_G[i][j][2]=rho*v*v+P;
                Array_G[i][j][3]=(Array_U[i][j][3]+P)*v;
            }
        }
    }

    void Boundaries (double Array_U[M+1][N+1][4])
    {
        for(int k=0 ; k<4; k++)
        {
            for (int i = 0 ; i<=M ; i++) {
                Array_U[i][0][k]=Array_U[i][1][k];
                Array_U[i][N][k]=Array_U[i][N-1][k];
            }
            for (int j = 0 ; j<=N ; j++) {
                Array_U[0][j][k]=Array_U[1][j][k];
                Array_U[M][j][k]=Array_U[M-1][j][k];
            }
        }
    }

    void printOutput(double U[M+1][N+1][4])
    {
        double x,y,dx,dy, u,v, rho,p;
        dx=(double(x_2-x_1))/double(M);
        dy=(double(y_2-y_1))/double(N);

        FILE *fp;
        fp=fopen("result.dat","w+");
        fprintf(fp,"%2.38s\n %20.60s\n %20.18s\t %2.3d\t %2.18s\t %2.3d\t %2.18s\n","TITLE = \"2D-EULER.dat\"","variables = \"x\", \"y\", \"rho\", \"u\", \"v\", \"p\"","zone i=", M+1,"j=",N+1,"f=point");
        for(int i=0; i<=M; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<=N; j++)
            {
                x=x_1+i*dx;
                y=y_1+j*dy;
                rho=U[i][j][0];
                u=U[i][j][1]/U[i][j][0];
                v=U[i][j][2]/U[i][j][0];
                p=(gama-1)*(U[i][j][3]-0.5*U[i][j][0]*(u*u+v*v));
                fprintf(fp,"%20.5f\t %20.5f\t %20.5f\t %20.5f\t %20.5f\t %20.5f\n",x,y,rho,u,v,p);
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
};
class Derivate
{
public:
    void get_derivative_values (double U[M+1][N+1][4],double dU_dX[M+1][N+1][4], double dU_dY[M+1][N+1][4],double dU_dT[M+1][N+1][4],double dF_dT[M+1][N+1][4],double dG_dT[M+1][N+1][4],double dF_dY[M+1][N+1][4],double dG_dX[M+1][N+1][4])
    {
        double gama_minus_1,gama_minus_3,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6;
        gama_minus_1=gama-1.0;
        gama_minus_3=gama-3.0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i <= M ; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0 ; j <= N ; j++)
            {
                double u=U[i][j][1]/U[i][j][0];
                double v=U[i][j][2]/U[i][j][0];

                a1=(-gama_minus_3*u*u-gama_minus_1*v*v)/2;
                a2=(-gama_minus_3*v*v-gama_minus_1*u*u)/2;
                a3=gama*u*(U[i][j][3]/U[i][j][0])-gama_minus_1*(u*u*u+u*v*v);
                a4=-gama*(U[i][j][3]/U[i][j][0])+(3*u*u+v*v)*gama_minus_1/2;
                a5=gama*v*(U[i][j][3]/U[i][j][0])-gama_minus_1*(v*v*v+u*u*v);
                a6=-gama*(U[i][j][3]/U[i][j][0])+(3*v*v+u*u)*gama_minus_1/2;

                dU_dT[i][j][0]=-dU_dX[i][j][1]-dU_dY[i][j][2];
                dU_dT[i][j][1]=a1*dU_dX[i][j][0]+gama_minus_3*u*dU_dX[i][j][1]+gama_minus_1*v*dU_dX[i][j][2]-gama_minus_1*dU_dX[i][j][3]+u*v*dU_dY[i][j][0]-v*dU_dY[i][j][1]-u*dU_dY[i][j][2];
                dU_dT[i][j][2]=u*v*dU_dX[i][j][0]-v*dU_dX[i][j][1]-u*dU_dX[i][j][2]+a2*dU_dY[i][j][0]+gama_minus_1*u*dU_dY[i][j][1]+gama_minus_3*v*dU_dY[i][j][2]-gama_minus_1*dU_dY[i][j][3];
                dU_dT[i][j][3]=a3*dU_dX[i][j][0]+a4*dU_dX[i][j][1]+gama_minus_1*u*v*dU_dX[i][j][2]-gama*u*dU_dX[i][j][3]+a5*dU_dY[i][j][0]+gama_minus_1*u*v*dU_dY[i][j][1]+a6*dU_dY[i][j][2]-gama*v*dU_dY[i][j][3];

                dF_dT[i][j][0]=dU_dT[i][j][1];
                dF_dT[i][j][1]=-a1*dU_dT[i][j][0]-gama_minus_3*u*dU_dT[i][j][1]-gama_minus_1*v*dU_dT[i][j][2]+gama_minus_1*dU_dT[i][j][3];
                dF_dT[i][j][2]=-u*v*dU_dT[i][j][0]+v*dU_dT[i][j][1]+u*dU_dT[i][j][2];
                dF_dT[i][j][3]=-a3*dU_dT[i][j][0]-a4*dU_dT[i][j][1]-gama_minus_1*u*v*dU_dT[i][j][2]+gama*u*dU_dT[i][j][3];

                dF_dY[i][j][0]=dU_dY[i][j][1];
                dF_dY[i][j][1]=-a1*dU_dY[i][j][0]-gama_minus_3*u*dU_dY[i][j][1]-gama_minus_1*v*dU_dY[i][j][2]+gama_minus_1*dU_dY[i][j][3];
                dF_dY[i][j][2]=-u*v*dU_dY[i][j][0]+v*dU_dY[i][j][1]+u*dU_dY[i][j][2];
                dF_dY[i][j][3]=-a3*dU_dY[i][j][0]-a4*dU_dY[i][j][1]-gama_minus_1*u*v*dU_dY[i][j][2]+gama*u*dU_dY[i][j][3];

                dG_dT[i][j][0]=dU_dT[i][j][2];
                dG_dT[i][j][1]=-u*v*dU_dT[i][j][0]+v*dU_dT[i][j][1]+u*dU_dT[i][j][2];
                dG_dT[i][j][2]=-a2*dU_dT[i][j][0]-gama_minus_1*u*dU_dT[i][j][1]-gama_minus_3*v*dU_dT[i][j][2]+gama_minus_1*dU_dT[i][j][3];
                dG_dT[i][j][3]=-a5*dU_dT[i][j][0]-gama_minus_1*u*v*dU_dT[i][j][1]-a6*dU_dT[i][j][2]+gama*v*dU_dT[i][j][3];

                dG_dX[i][j][0]=dU_dX[i][j][2];
                dG_dX[i][j][1]=-u*v*dU_dX[i][j][0]+v*dU_dX[i][j][1]+u*dU_dX[i][j][2];
                dG_dX[i][j][2]=-a2*dU_dX[i][j][0]-gama_minus_1*u*dU_dX[i][j][1]-gama_minus_3*v*dU_dX[i][j][2]+gama_minus_1*dU_dX[i][j][3];
                dG_dX[i][j][3]=-a5*dU_dX[i][j][0]-gama_minus_1*u*v*dU_dX[i][j][1]-a6*dU_dX[i][j][2]+gama*v*dU_dX[i][j][3];

            }
        }
    }

    // Get dudx and dudy for complete time step
    void dU_dX_dU_dY_n(double U[M+1][N+1][4],double U_p[M+1][N+1][4],double dU_dX[M+1][N+1][4], double dU_dY[M+1][N+1][4], double dU_dT[M+1][N+1][4],double dt)
    {
        double dU_dX_plus,dU_dX_min,dx, dU_dY_plus,dU_dY_min,dy;
        dx=(double(x_2-x_1))/double(M);
        dy=(double(y_2-y_1))/double(N);
        for(int i = 1; i <= M ; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 1 ; j <= N ; j++)
            {
                for(int k = 0 ; k < 4 ; k++)
                {
                    dU_dX_plus=(U_p[i][j-1][k]+dU_dT[i][j-1][k]*dt/2+U_p[i][j][k]+dU_dT[i][j][k]*dt/2-2*U[i][j][k])/dx;
                    dU_dX_min=-(U_p[i-1][j-1][k]+dU_dT[i-1][j-1][k]*dt/2+U_p[i-1][j][k]+dU_dT[i-1][j][k]*dt/2-2*U[i][j][k])/dx;
                    dU_dX[i][j][k]=Wfunct(dU_dX_plus, dU_dX_min);

                    dU_dY_plus=(U_p[i][j][k]+dU_dT[i][j][k]*dt/2+U_p[i-1][j][k]+dU_dT[i-1][j][k]*dt/2-2*U[i][j][k])/dy;
                    dU_dY_min=-(U_p[i-1][j-1][k]+dU_dT[i-1][j-1][k]*dt/2+U_p[i][j-1][k]+dU_dT[i][j-1][k]*dt/2-2*U[i][j][k])/dy;
                    dU_dY[i][j][k]=Wfunct(dU_dY_plus, dU_dY_min);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Get dudx and dudy for half time step
    void dU_dX_dU_dY_p(double U[M+1][N+1][4],double U_p[M+1][N+1][4],double dU_dX[M+1][N+1][4], double dU_dY[M+1][N+1][4], double dU_dT[M+1][N+1][4],double dt)
    {
        double dU_dX_plus,dU_dX_min,dx, dU_dY_plus,dU_dY_min,dy;
        dx=(double(x_2-x_1))/double(M);
        dy=(double(y_2-y_1))/double(N);

        for(int i = 1 ; i < M ; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 1 ; j < N ; j++)
            {
                for(int k = 0 ; k < 4 ; k++)
                {
                    dU_dX_plus=(U[i+1][j+1][k]+dU_dT[i+1][j+1][k]*dt/2+U[i+1][j][k]+dU_dT[i+1][j][k]*dt/2-2*U_p[i][j][k])/dx;
                    dU_dX_min=-(U[i][j+1][k]+dU_dT[i][j+1][k]*dt/2+U[i][j][k]+dU_dT[i][j][k]*dt/2-2*U_p[i][j][k])/dx;
                    dU_dX[i][j][k]=Wfunct(dU_dX_plus, dU_dX_min);

                    dU_dY_plus=(U[i+1][j+1][k]+dU_dT[i+1][j+1][k]*dt/2+U[i][j+1][k]+dU_dT[i][j+1][k]*dt/2-2*U_p[i][j][k])/dy;
                    dU_dY_min=-(U[i][j][k]+dU_dT[i][j][k]*dt/2+U[i+1][j][k]+dU_dT[i+1][j][k]*dt/2-2*U_p[i][j][k])/dy;
                    dU_dY[i][j][k]=Wfunct(dU_dY_plus, dU_dY_min);
                }
            }
        }
    }




private:
    double Wfunct(double value_plus, double value_min)
    {
        return (pow(fabs(value_plus),alpha)*value_min+pow(fabs(value_min),alpha)*value_plus)/(pow(fabs(value_plus),alpha)+pow(fabs(value_min),alpha)+1e-8);
    }

};

class CESE: public Derivate, Fluid {
    public:
    void CE_SE_method (double U[M+1][N+1][4],double U_p[M+1][N+1][4],double dU_dX[M+1][N+1][4],double dU_dY[M+1][N+1][4],double dU_dT[M+1][N+1][4],double F[M+1][N+1][4],double dF_dY[M+1][N+1][4],double dF_dT[M+1][N+1][4],double G[M+1][N+1][4],double dG_dX[M+1][N+1][4],double dG_dT[M+1][N+1][4])
    {

        double dt,t,dx,dy,U1,G1,F1;
        dx=(double(x_2-x_1))/double(M);
        dy=(double(y_2-y_1))/double(N);
        t=0;

        // Initial_Values(U, U_p, dU_dX, dU_dY); To be removed of the function and will be put before the program is run.

        while(t<Time)
        {
            dt=CFL(U);
            t=t+dt;
            printf("t=%f\n",t);
            Boundaries(U);
            get_F(U,F);
            get_G(U,G);
            get_derivative_values (U,dU_dX,dU_dY,dU_dT,dF_dT,dG_dT,dF_dY,dG_dX);
            // GET U_p
            for(int i = 0 ; i < M ; i++) // To get U_prime
            {
                for(int j = 0 ; j < N ; j++)
                {
                    for(int k = 0 ; k < 4 ; k++)
                    {
                        U1=U[i][j][k]+0.25*dx*dU_dX[i][j][k]+0.25*dy*dU_dY[i][j][k]+U[i+1][j][k]-0.25*dx*dU_dX[i+1][j][k]+0.25*dy*dU_dY[i+1][j][k]+U[i+1][j+1][k]-0.25*dx*dU_dX[i+1][j+1][k]-0.25*dy*dU_dY[i+1][j+1][k]+U[i][j+1][k]+0.25*dx*dU_dX[i][j+1][k]-0.25*dy*dU_dY[i][j+1][k];

                        G1=G[i][j][k]+0.25*dx*dG_dX[i][j][k]+0.25*dt*dG_dT[i][j][k]+G[i+1][j][k]-0.25*dx*dG_dX[i+1][j][k]+0.25*dt*dG_dT[i+1][j][k]-G[i+1][j+1][k]+0.25*dx*dG_dX[i+1][j+1][k]-0.25*dt*dG_dT[i+1][j+1][k]-G[i][j+1][k]-0.25*dx*dG_dX[i][j+1][k]-0.25*dt*dG_dT[i][j+1][k];

                        F1=F[i][j][k]+0.25*dy*dF_dY[i][j][k]+0.25*dt*dF_dT[i][j][k]-F[i+1][j][k]-0.25*dy*dF_dY[i+1][j][k]-0.25*dt*dF_dT[i+1][j][k]-F[i+1][j+1][k]+0.25*dy*dF_dY[i+1][j+1][k]-0.25*dt*dF_dT[i+1][j+1][k]+F[i][j+1][k]-0.25*dy*dF_dY[i][j+1][k]+0.25*dt*dF_dT[i][j+1][k];

                        U_p[i][j][k]=0.25*U1+(0.25*dt/dy)*G1+(0.25*dt/dx)*F1;
                    }
                }
            }


            dU_dX_dU_dY_p(U,U_p,dU_dX,dU_dY,dU_dT,dt);
            get_F(U_p,F);
            get_G(U_p,G);
            get_derivative_values (U_p,dU_dX,dU_dY,dU_dT,dF_dT,dG_dT,dF_dY,dG_dX);
            for(int i = 1 ; i < M ; i++) // To get U
            {
                for(int j = 1 ; j < N ; j++)
                {
                    for(int k = 0 ; k < 4 ; k++)
                    {
                        U1=U_p[i-1][j-1][k]+0.25*dx*dU_dX[i-1][j-1][k]+0.25*dy*dU_dY[i-1][j-1][k]+U_p[i][j-1][k]-0.25*dx*dU_dX[i][j-1][k]+0.25*dy*dU_dY[i][j-1][k]+U_p[i][j][k]-0.25*dx*dU_dX[i][j][k]-0.25*dy*dU_dY[i][j][k]+U_p[i-1][j][k]+0.25*dx*dU_dX[i-1][j][k]-0.25*dy*dU_dY[i-1][j][k];

                        G1=G[i-1][j-1][k]+0.25*dx*dG_dX[i-1][j-1][k]+0.25*dt*dG_dT[i-1][j-1][k]+G[i][j-1][k]-0.25*dx*dG_dX[i][j-1][k]+0.25*dt*dG_dT[i][j-1][k]-G[i][j][k]+0.25*dx*dG_dX[i][j][k]-0.25*dt*dG_dT[i][j][k]-G[i-1][j][k]-0.25*dx*dG_dX[i-1][j][k]-0.25*dt*dG_dT[i-1][j][k];

                        F1=F[i-1][j-1][k]+0.25*dy*dF_dY[i-1][j-1][k]+0.25*dt*dF_dT[i-1][j-1][k]-F[i][j-1][k]-0.25*dy*dF_dY[i][j-1][k]-0.25*dt*dF_dT[i][j-1][k]-F[i][j][k]+0.25*dy*dF_dY[i][j][k]-0.25*dt*dF_dT[i][j][k]+F[i-1][j][k]-0.25*dy*dF_dY[i-1][j][k]+0.25*dt*dF_dT[i-1][j][k];

                        U[i][j][k]=0.25*U1+(0.25*dt/dy)*G1+(0.25*dt/dx)*F1;
                    }
                }
            }
            //Boundaries(U);
            dU_dX_dU_dY_n(U,U_p,dU_dX,dU_dY,dU_dT,dt);

        }
    }
private:
    double CFL (double U[M+1][N+1][4])
    {
        double dx=double(x_2-x_1)/double(M),dy=double(y_2-y_1)/double(N);
        double max_vel, vel, p,v,u;
        max_vel=1E-8;
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= M ; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1 ; j <= N ; j++)
            {
                u=U[i][j][1]/U[i][j][0];
                v=U[i][j][2]/U[i][j][0];
                p=(gama-1)*(U[i][j][3]-0.5*U[i][j][0]*(u*u+v*v));
                vel = sqrt(gama*p/U[i][j][0])+sqrt(u*u+v*v);
                if (vel>max_vel)max_vel=vel;
            }
        }
        return Cf*dx*dy/(dy*max_vel+dx*max_vel);
    }
};





int main( )
{
    Fluid U_func;
    CESE Calculate;

    clock_t start,finish;
    double duration;
    start=clock();

    U_func.SetInitialConditions(0, M, 0, N, rho1, u1, v1, p1);
    U_func.SetInitialConditions(M/2, M, 0, N/2, rho2, u2, v2, p2);
    U_func.SetInitialConditions(0, M/2, N/2, N, rho3, u3, v3, p3);
    U_func.SetInitialConditions(0, M/2, 0, N/2, rho4, u4, v4, p4);
    Calculate.CE_SE_method(U_func.Array_U, U_func.Array_Prime, U_func.dU_dX, U_func.dU_dY, U_func.dU_dT, U_func.Array_F, U_func.dF_dY, U_func.dF_dT, U_func.Array_G, U_func.dG_dX, U_func.dG_dT);

    U_func.printOutput(U_func.Array_U);
    finish=clock();
    duration=(double)(finish-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout << "Complete in \n" << duration << "s \n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger to pin point your problem and then put that code snippet here if you still haven't found the bug!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `fluid` object will use quite a bit of space: There are 10 arrays of 106 * 106 * 4 * 8 bytes (assuming `double` is 8 bytes). That's 360K per array, or just under 4MB in total.

The stack-space that you are trying to use in `main` to store your `fluid` object is limited. In general, using megabytes of stack-space is a recipe for this sort of crash. It may be possible to increase the stack-space, but it's most likely going to be relatively limited, so if you ever expect to run more than around 100-200 elements in your dimensions, you will need to come up with a different strategy.

There are several possible solutions - all involve more or less direct use of dynamic allocation:

1. Use `std::vector<std::vector<double [4]>>` for your storage in the `fluid` object.
2. Use dynamic memory allocation for the `fluid` object - e.g. `fluid* U_func = new fluid;`
3. Re-organise your calculation data to be stored in a `struct data { ... }` and have a vector of such data. This may be more complex and not necessarily help performance however.

Edit: I forgot to make the pun about asking on StackOverflow.com how to solve a Stack Overflow problem. Sorry, sometimes I find myself amusing, but nobody else does... :)

Comment: The best solution would be to define a class for the `[N+1][M+1][4]` structures, probably using a one dimension `std::vector` as the data container.  Or more likely, define a `struct` with the four elements (which sort of seem to have different semantics), and then a generic `Matrix2D` class (which will be generally useful to anyone doing this sort of work).

Comment: I might add that it's almost always an error to require such matrix sizes to be compile time constants.  It's far preferable to make them invocation parameters, either from the command line or a configuration file, rather than to have to recompile the entire program any time you  want to change them.

Comment: @JamesKanze I am planing to make a configuration file, but first I am "drafting" the code. Thanks for your suggestions!!

Comment: @heri-salmas Which is a good way to go, but there's no point in not using data structures which will support the dynamic sizing later.  (And I'd go with a matrix class even in the draft.  It's not that difficult to write, and you'll want it later anyway.)

Comment: Thanks @JamesKanze I will try it! Lets hope you won't see another question from me asking how to do it correctly. :)